# Pycharm Terminal does not seem to use virtual environment

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I have a venv setup with Python 3.7 with several packages installed. I installed them using the UI in settings and the scripts run fine.

However, when I go to the Terminal window and try to run my script there there, it gives me an error message saying "No module named xxxx".

Running python3 run_glue.py, it curiously gives me the following error:

```
sh-3.2$ python3 run_glue.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_glue.py", line 27, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from torch._C import *

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libshm.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

It seems that it is looking at a python 3.6 environment despite my virtual environment being 3.7. I checked my settings and I dont see why it would be looking at the python 3.6 environment.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: You should be able to see current virtualenvironment in the toolbar at the bottom (for me bottom right). You can also press it and select from the available. Does that pop up menu show something? Also, in the same terminal, you can check which is your current environment by executing `which python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate your environment first:

`sh-3.2$ source path_of_your_venv/bin/activate`

You should now see an `(env)` before your bash prompt:

`(env) sh-3.2$`

Then you can check if `python3` is correctly referencing the environment by `which python3`.

Alternatively, execute `python3` directly from within your environment:

`./path_of_your_venv/bin/python3 run_glue.py`.